# Leaflet - Creating LayerGroups Dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

**Is it possible to create LayerGroups Dynamically?** I'm developing an web map that shows the tree species that exists in the parks, an i'm trying to create a LayerGroup for each species so that with a LayerControl i can hide and show certain species, for the sake of testing, i have been creating LayerGroups like this:

```
l1 = new L.LayerGroup();
//...
l100 = new L.LayerGroup();
```

And i'm sure that there is a way to do it depending on the number of species that exists, i have tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSpecies ; i++) {
  l[i] = new L.LayerGroup();
}
```

But this way, i cant do this:

```
l[0].addLayer(marker);
```

What is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Do you want to implement something similar to [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)?

Comment: @Iavor well, taking the example of layerGroups/layerControl on the leaflet website, they have a LayerGroup called **cities**, the cities here, are my **tree species**, if i have several tree species, how can i create a layerGroup for each of them dynamically?

Comment: Wouldn't you just create a new layer group for each species? What dynamic behavior are you after?

Comment: @Iavor i want to be able to hide and show layerGroups in a layerControl(done), and to create the exact same number of layer groups of the number of species on my DB, so that i can hide specie1, specie8, etc.. (hiding the layer l1, l8), i hope i clarify it more.. maybe i'm just doing the hard way

Comment: Have you tried implementing what you're looking for? Did you run into any errors?

Comment: @Istopopoki example is what i was looking for

Comment: Ah, okay. Nice! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
For example:

```
var layerGroups = {}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    layerGroups[i] = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    layerGroups[i].addLayer(L.marker([i,i]))
}
```

You can try it here : https://jsfiddle.net/mckbda9y/6/

Comment: **Thank you!** i was going the right way, if your example works, i must be doing something wrong, i will find what's causing the error.

Comment: probably, but there is something more, but don't need to worry about it, i have to find it myself